# Problems with coding slider for iOS

Tags: ios, slider

Hi guys so i am trying to create a slider with 7 different sections, as you slider the slider the label would change.

I have linked it all with the .m .h so the label interacts with the slider etc files but only the ones with the value 0 , 0.5 and 1 seem to be working?

Can someone point me in the right direction of what im doing wrong? Im new to iOS development and this is my first time using a slider.

Here is my code in the .m file for the slider

```
-(IBAction)slidetheslider:(id)sender; {
q4label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f",question4slider.value];
 if (question4slider.value == 0) {
     q4label2.text = @"> 2.5 dots L";
                      }
if (question4slider.value == 0.2) {
    q4label2.text = @" 2.5 dots L";
}
if (question4slider.value == 0.3) {
    q4label2.text = @"1-2 dots L";
}
if (question4slider.value == 0.5) {
    q4label2.text = @"< 1 dot L/R";
}
if (question4slider.value == 0.7) {
    q4label2.text = @"1-2 dots R";
}
if (question4slider.value == 0.8) {
    q4label2.text = @"2.5 dots R";
}
if (question4slider.value == 1) {
    q4label2.text = @"> 2.5dots R";
}
```

}

Comment: perhaps this [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-uislider-basics-for-apple-ios/) will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question4slider.value is a floating point number.  Due to the way it is stored, it won't be represented exactly in memory, sometimes 0.2 is stored as 0.01999999999. So don't use absolute comparisons.  Try this instead:

```
-(IBAction)slidetheslider:(id)sender; {
q4label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f",question4slider.value];
 if (question4slider.value < 0.2) {
     q4label2.text = @"> 2.5 dots L";
                      }
} else if (question4slider.value < 0.3) {
    q4label2.text = @" 2.5 dots L";
}
else if (question4slider.value < 0.5) {
    q4label2.text = @"1-2 dots L";
}
else if (question4slider.value < 0.7) {
    q4label2.text = @"< 1 dot L/R";
}
else if (question4slider.value < 0.8) {
    q4label2.text = @"1-2 dots R";
}
else if (question4slider.value < 1.0) {
    q4label2.text = @"2.5 dots R";
}
else
    q4label2.text = @"> 2.5dots R";
}
```

Comment: Hi Owen thanks for the reply i have adjusted the code but still having problems its coming up with an error message on the lines.
Expected identifier or '(' ?

Comment: Edit : Dont worry all sorted now! Thank you for all the help!

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as answered so others will not continue to investigate it.